# Strange session variables behavior and devise before and after signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I set some session variables before my users login with devise.. Expecting them to be available after they sign in as well..

Sometimes Sessions variables are kept after signing in with devise (before signing in) and sometimes the sessions variables I set before signing in are not transferred over to the signed in session...

Have you noticed this too? Why is this happening?

Comment: With iPhone session will be maintained while with Android every time you will get the new session, I already faced this issue! because android every time opens a new browser

Comment: mmm interesting, well my users claim to be using Chrome on the PC, not sure it will apply there, but yeah, interesting that it differs like that from browser to browser.. what a pain